# charindex thrown off by extended characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, varchar, character-set, encoding

I've got a column with a filenames stored in a nvarchar(255). I'm trying to parse out the file extension using

```
reverse( left( reverse(filename), charindex('.', reverse(filename) ) -1 ) )
```

This works great for most of my records, however some are failing due to charindex returning 0 while a '.' is definitely part of the string.

I think I've isolated it to an issue with accented characters and a few others.

One of them I have is ité.pdf, when reversed, charindex is not finding the '.'

```
fdp.́eti
```

I've taken to converting it to it's hex representation to narrow down what's going on using

```
cast(reverse(filename) as varbinary(max))

0x6600640070002E000103650074006900
```

From what I can work out The '.' is 2E 00. 01 03 65 00 is the 'é' which is encoded differently than the others I have in the same column.

Since 2E 00 comes first I would still expect `charindex` to get a match, but it's returning me 0, which in turn make the call to `LEFT` fail.

Am I missing something obvious here? Converted to HEX it seems the '.' I am looking for is definitely there, but the character after is tripping `charindex` somehow.

**EDIT: Simplified test**

When outputting the string there is clearly a ., but charindex is not finding it?

```
select charindex('.', cast(0x6600640070002E000103650074006900 as nvarchar(max)))
```

Fiddle: 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cda6f0a77fa9e206bff9217ec58be075

Comment: which version of sql server are you running?

Comment: @kevinnwhat 2016

Comment: @McNets - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cda6f0a77fa9e206bff9217ec58be075

Comment: You could try by casting it as varchar(255). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3241a45188fdedd408964fa2eab07736

Comment: casting it to varchar works, I'll use that if you want to post it as an answer. I wouldn't mind knowing what's going on with the nvarchar if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems related to a collation or encoding issue.

I'd check database and column collations to ensure both are the same.

**Server collation**

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation')) AS 'Server Collation';
```

**Database collation**

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.databases
WHERE 
    name = 'DBName';
```

**Column collation**

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.columns 
WHERE 
    name = N'ColumnName';
```

Quoted from MS-Docs [Collation precedende](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#functions-and-collation)

> Functions and Collation
>
> THE CAST, CONVERT, and COLLATE functions are collation sensitive for
>   char, varchar, and text data types. If the input and output of the
>   CAST and CONVERT functions are character strings, the output string
>   has the collation label of the input string. If the input is not a
>   character string, the output string is Coercible-default and assigned
>   the collation of the current database for the connection, or the
>   database that contains the user-defined function, stored procedure, or
>   trigger in which the CAST or CONVERT is referenced.
>
> For the built-in functions that return a string but do not take a
>   string input, the result string is Coercible-default and is assigned
>   either the collation of the current database, or the collation of the
>   database that contains the user-defined function, stored procedure, or
>   trigger in which the function is referenced.
>
> The following functions are collation-sensitive and their output
>   strings have the collation label of the input string:
>
> CHARINDEX, REPLACE, DIFFERENCE, REVERSE, ISNUMERIC, RIGHT, LEFT, SOUNDEX, LEN, STUFF, LOWER, SUBSTRING, PATINDEX, UPPER

Let me suggest to have a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196652/110455) or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163433/110455) answers of [Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky) about UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding values for VARCHAR and NVARCHAR.

By now you can try by CASTING it to VARCHAR(255) before use CHARINDEX.

I've tried to reproduce it in one of my servers in this way:

```
DECLARE @t VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x6600640070002E000103650074006900;
DECLARE @vt VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT CAST(@t AS nvarchar(MAX));

---------
fdp.́eti


SET @vt =  CAST(CAST(@t AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@vt), CHARINDEX(N'.', REVERSE(@vt))-1));

-------
´eti
```

Note it returns the accent as a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract extension without using reverse function:

```
declare @x nvarchar(max) = reverse(cast(cast(0x6600640070002E000103650074006900 as varbinary(255)) as nvarchar(255))) collate LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC;

select substring(@x, charindex('.', @x) +1 , LEN(@x) - charindex('.', @x))
```

If you have multiple dots, then you may force TSQL to use binary collation or cast to varchar:

```
select reverse( left( reverse(@x collate LATIN1_GENERAL_100_BIN), charindex('.', reverse(@x collate LATIN1_GENERAL_100_BIN) ) -1 ) )

select reverse( left( reverse(cast(@x AS varchar(255))), charindex('.', reverse(cast(@x AS varchar(255)) )) -1 ) )
```

Comment: That won't work if there's multiple dots in the filename though, that's why I was using reverse.

Comment: select charindex('.', cast(0x6600640070002E000103650074006900 as nvarchar(max)))